# Core-plot label not display on top of each bar column

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I am new with Core-plot. I would like to add label about the number on each of bar column on CPBarPlot. I knew that I must implement this method of CPBarPlotDataSource delegate:

```
 -(CPTextLayer *)barLabelForBarPlot:(CPBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:
     (NSUInteger)index;
```

But even I implemented that method, nothing happen, the graph displays without label on top of each bar. Do I miss something?

This is my code:

```
- (void) constructBarChart {
 //create bar chart from theme
 barChart = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
 CPTheme *theme = [CPTheme themeNamed:kCPPlainWhiteTheme];
 [barChart applyTheme:theme];
 hostView.hostedLayer = barChart;
 barChart.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;

 barChart.paddingTop = 30.0;
 barChart.paddingBottom = 30.0;
 barChart.paddingLeft = 30.0;
 barChart.paddingRight = 30.0;


 // setup plot space
 CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace*)barChart.defaultPlotSpace;
 plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
 plotSpace.delegate = self;
 plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(10.0f)];
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(10.0f)];
 plotSpace.globalXRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(20.0f)];
 plotSpace.globalYRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(20.0f)];


 // Grid line styles
    CPLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.75;
    majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPColor colorWithGenericGray:0.2]
         colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75];

    CPLineStyle *minorGridLineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
    minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.25;
    minorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPColor whiteColor]
         colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];

    CPLineStyle *redLineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
    redLineStyle.lineWidth = 10.0;
    redLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPColor redColor]
         colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]; 


 //Axis
 CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet*)barChart.axisSet;
 CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
 CPLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
 lineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor blackColor];
 x.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
 x.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromString(@"5");
 x.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;


 CPXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
 y.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
 y.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromString(@"1");
 y.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
 y.isFloatingAxis = YES;


 CPBarPlot *barPlot = [CPBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPColor redColor] horizontalBars:NO];
 barPlot.baseValue = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
 barPlot.dataSource = self;
 barPlot.delegate = self;
 barPlot.identifier = @"Bar Plot 1";
 [barChart addPlot:barPlot toPlotSpace: plotSpace];
}

- (NSUInteger) numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot*)plot {
 if ([plot isKindOfClass:[CPBarPlot class]]) {
  return 16;
 } else {
  return [dataGraph count];
 }
}

- (NSNumber *)numberForPlot: (CPPlot*) plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger) index {
 NSDecimalNumber *num = nil;
 if ([plot isKindOfClass:[CPBarPlot class]]) {
  switch (fieldEnum) {
   case CPBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
    num = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
    break;
   case CPBarPlotFieldBarLength:
    num = (NSDecimalNumber *) [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:(index + 1)];
    break;
  }
 } else {
  num = [[dataGraph objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:(fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y")];
 }
 return num;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Plot Space Delegate Methods 

-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)proposedDisplacementVector {
 CGPoint result = CGPointMake(proposedDisplacementVector.x, 0.0);
 return result;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Bar Plot Delegate Methods

- (CPTextLayer *) barLabelForBarPlot:(CPBarPlot *) barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger) index {
 CPTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", index+1]];
 return textLayer;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The labeling method changed recently. It's just a name change; it works the same as before. The new declaration is:

```
-(CPLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

Also, this method should return autoreleased objects to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: No, it is still "barLabelForBarPlot" method. Because I have just downloaded it from CorePlot website. And I look for CPBarPlot class, it has "barLabelForBarPlot" method.
Anyway, thank you for your reply.

Comment: is it possible bar chart with same color as label have with core plot,i can display bar chart but have some default blue color.thank you very much for reading.i hope some thing related to this u know.

Comment: @Pooja, can you please post working code that worked for you in answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hope Someone will find this useful, Who doesn't know that how to display the label on top of the bar. I have implemented the CPTPlotDataSource  as below,

[image]

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx{

    CPTMutableTextStyle *ts = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    ts.textAlignment = CPTTextAlignmentCenter;
    ts.color = [CPTColor redColor];

    CPTTextLayer *tl = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"5" style:ts];

    return tl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. (for [core plot 1.6](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/releases))

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
{
       CPTMutableTextStyle *ts = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
       ts.textAlignment = CPTTextAlignmentCenter;
       ts.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
       ts.fontSize = 12;
       plot.labelOffset = 0;
       CPTTextLayer *tl = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",index] style:ts];
       return tl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method signature now changed to

> -(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index

or

> -(NSArray *) dataLabelsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange